# Set return value equal to variable objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a function called addFixturesToBody and it returns a variable and I use it like this...

```
    [[GB2ShapeCache sharedShapeCache] addFixturesToBody:body forShapeName:@"egg3"];
```

How to I set my variable called eggFixture equal to the return value from addFixturesToBody... I tried this...

```
    *eggFixture = [[GB2ShapeCache sharedShapeCache] addFixturesToBody:body forShapeName:@"egg3"];
```

But it ends with a runtime error

Help?

Comment: What is the type of the variable returned by `addFixturesToBody`?

Comment: B2Fixture.. Its part of box2d the physics engine im using

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is t do something like this:

```
GB2ShapeCache *cache = [GB2ShapeCache sharedShapeCache];
[cache addFixturesToBody:body forShapeName:@"egg3"];
```

Given you didn't paste in any method stubs, I'm guessing that the `addFixturesToBody:body:forShapeName:` method has a void return value (and hence the runtime exception).

Comment: No it doesn't have a void return value I'm sure of that much ;) I think it was setting the return from  [g2shapecache sharedShapeCache] and they wernt close to the same variable types, so now would i set [cache...egg3"]; equal to eggFixture

Answer (score 0):

`addFixturesToBody` doesn't return any values - its return type is `void`.  What value were you trying to get?

The method signature is:

```
-(void) addFixturesToBody:(b2Body*)body forShapeName:(NSString*)shape
```

This means it doesn't return any values.

Comment: I rewrote the code because i needed to set a b2fixture so i could us the b2contactlistener

Comment: Can you please post the code you used, I am trying to do the same!